# Error updating table in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am getting the following error while updating data to a table with lookup in SSIS:

> Source: "Microsoft SQL Native Client" 
>   Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "The
>   incoming tabular data stream (TDS)
>   remote procedure call (RPC) protocol
>   stream is incorrect. The RPC name is
>   invalid.".

I deleted the DFD and recreated again but getting the same error. I am updating the table with OLEDB command.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the connection to your Sql Server to use OLEDB instead of SQL Native Client?